Integrating tailwind into storybook7 using webpack
Been struggling with this problem for hours :(
I have a separate project with a component that uses shadcn and tailwind.css. And I want to move this component to another project that uses storybook7 version, and then I will implement other components there. Also this project is monorepo. I have almost everything worked out, but tailwind styles don't work for all components.
storybook (7 version) details
/apps/design-system/.storybook/main.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../../../packages/*/src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../../../apps/*/src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../../../packages/*/*/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  staticDirs: ['../../../packages/component-library/public'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    '@storybook/preset-scss',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer'),
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../packages/component-library/uikit'),
    });

    config.resolve.alias = {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../packages/component-library/uikit'),
      '@ui': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../packages/component-library/uikit/ui'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../packages/component-library/uikit/components'),
    };

    return config;
  },
};

/apps/design-system/.storybook/preview.js
import 'shared/src/index.css'
import '../../../packages/component-library/uikit/global.css'

/** @type { import('@storybook/react').Preview } */
const preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;

tailwind details
/packages/component-library/uikit/global.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --primary: 142 86% 28%;
    --primary-foreground: 356 29% 98%;
    --secondary: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --secondary-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --muted: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --muted-foreground: 240 3.8% 45%;
    --accent: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --accent-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --destructive: 0 72% 51%;
    --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --border: 240 5.9% 90%;
    --input: 240 5.9% 90%;
    --ring: 142 86% 28%;
    --radius: 0.5rem;
  }
}

@layer base {
  * {
    @apply border-border;
  }

  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground font-body;
  }

  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    @apply font-heading;
  }
}

/packages/component-library/uikit/postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

/packages/component-library/uikit/tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

import { fontFamily } from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import tailwindAnimate from 'tailwindcss-animate';

export default {
  content: ['./components/**/*.{js,jsx}', './ui/**/*.{js,jsx}'],
  prefix: '',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        heading: ['var(--font-heading)', ...fontFamily.sans],
        body: ['var(--font-body)', ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      colors: {
        border: 'hsl(var(--border))',
        input: 'hsl(var(--input))',
        ring: 'hsl(var(--ring))',
        background: 'hsl(var(--background))',
        foreground: 'hsl(var(--foreground))',
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--primary))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--primary-foreground))',
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--secondary))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))',
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--destructive))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))',
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--muted))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--muted-foreground))',
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--accent))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--accent-foreground))',
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--popover))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--popover-foreground))',
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--card))',
          foreground: 'hsl(var(--card-foreground))',
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        xl: `calc(var(--radius) + 4px)`,
        lg: `var(--radius)`,
        md: `calc(var(--radius) - 2px)`,
        sm: `calc(var(--radius) - 4px)`,
      },
      keyframes: {
        'accordion-down': {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)' },
        },
        'accordion-up': {
          from: { height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)' },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        'accordion-down': 'accordion-down 0.2s ease-out',
        'accordion-up': 'accordion-up 0.2s ease-out',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [tailwindAnimate],
};

But I get an error as a result
Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError
(2:7) /Users/yurii/projects/datarama_frontend/packages/component-library/uikit/global.css Unknown word
1 |

2 |       import API from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
|       ^
3 |       import domAPI from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
4 |       import insertFn from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";

ERROR in ../../node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[9].use[1]!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].use[2]!../../packages/component-library/uikit/global.css
Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError
(2:7) /Users/yurii/projects/datarama_frontend/packages/component-library/uikit/global.css Unknown word
1 |

2 |       import API from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
|       ^
3 |       import domAPI from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
4 |       import insertFn from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";

I realize it's because my webpack is trying to parse the css as a js file. But I don't understand why? What am I doing wrong? Please help me fix it!

This repository with a similar stack + webpack customization helped me. https://github.com/arevalolance/design-system-template/tree/main
